# Where can I find or buy recipes?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I have acquired about a million reagents that can used to create potions. I went to use the alchemy table in Gorhart and it said I didn't have any recipes. I went back to the shop keeper, assuming that she would have some recipes since she sells potions. Alas, she doesn't have any.

Where can I find or buy recipes to create potions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to discover recipes for alchemy.

1) Experiment! When you access the alchemy table, you have two options - Create, and Experiment. Experiment allows you to discover new recipes by combining multiple ingredients together. Higher levels of your alchemy skill allow you to place more ingredients in the experiment process, allowing you to discover more potent recipes. Once you've discovered a recipe through experimentation, it is permanently acquired and listed in your Create menu for ease of use.

2) Purchase/find recipes. You can find recipes in various locations, and purchase them from several vendors as well. One example of such is...

> ...in Star Camp, not too far from the start of the game, you can access the Fence that has numerous alchemical recipes for sale. Not sure if this indicates the relative scarcity / secrecy of potion recipes in general, but it's a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

As was stated, recipies can be experimented for, found or purchased.

You can also obtain them by hitting Alchemy milestone 10 which will reveal all the recipes.

Some users have already speculated that you could save your game, use a Fateweaver to reset your skills, max out your alchemy, record all the recipes and restore your saved game and then use the reagents to "experiment" for the recipes that you now "know".